# Why can't I get the Page.Title within an httpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I am tracking page titles in an ASP.net webforms application. The code below works however page.Title always throws a System.NullReferenceException even though the page I am tracking has a title. Why?

```
public class TrackingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.PostAcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(Application_PostAcquireRequestState);
    }

    void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

            Log(page.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might be doing it too soon.

Comment: where do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I can only see it being that page variable isn't initialized. Does HttpContext.Current.Handler actually contain a memory address or value? If it's giving you a System.NullReferenceException then it is exactly that - Title, or the thing that is calling Title is null.